# How to refer to a helm chart in the same repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to maintain a few Helm charts in the same repository that refer to each other in their respective `requirements.yaml` files.  How should these charts refer to each other's relative paths?

For local development I can use the `file://` protocol as in

```
name: chart-name
repository: file://../chart-name
```

However when I move to a hosted repository I will need to change this.  I would prefer that this directory of charts does not need to have its final location baked into its repository.yaml files.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

When you move to a hosted repository, won't you have had to publish each chart? 
If so, as long as you don't have cyclic dependencies, publish each chart in dependent order to your hosted repo and then update requirements.yaml.

i.e. if you have 3 charts A,B and C.

1. A has no dependency on B nor C
2. B depends on A
3. C depends on B

Publish A to the hosted repo, update B's requirements to point to the hosted repo name of A, then publish B and repeat the update process for C.

I'm doing something similar but I don't use a hosted repo. I already have a large Ansible setup so I wrote a role which installs charts directly from directories. There's a single git repo with all (currently 7) my charts and this minus running a helm server is a similar process. The obvious downside being the manual update of requirements, but I'm not sure there's any other choice on that.

**EDIT**

A bit hacky but could work:

To avoid editing dependencies one way is to also run your chart repo locally.
If your repo is available at `charts.domain.com`, add a dependency to this as per usual

```
dependencies:
  - name: my-chart
    repository: http://charts.domain.com
    version: 0.0.1
```

then, when you develop locally, add an entry to your hosts file which points `charts.domain.com` to your `localhost` charts.

Sample workflow might be something like:

```
mkdir my-charts
mv my-char-a-0.0.1.tgz my-charts/
helm repo index my-charts/ --url http://charts.domain.com
```

Now serve the index/repo generated from localhost. This way your dependency is always to charts.domain.com

Depending on which remote host you're using you could just rsync this local index to your remote when you're happy to release and that way you reduce the chance of your local and remotes diverging.

Again, caveat being you need to enable disable this host entry depending on if your developing or wanting to use the live repo. 
You can always script the editing of host file entry.

Comment: "The obvious downside being the manual update of requirements, but I'm not sure there's any other choice on that."----

Yeah, to be clear this is the crux of my problem.  I'm entirely capable of publishing everything.  I'd just rather not bake the name of the repository explicitly if I can avoid it.  I'd like to say "look in the repository where you're getting this chart"

Comment: In many systems we like to have the concept of relocatability, meaning that we want to be able to deploy an artifact to different places and we expect that the thing keeps working. If we need to hard-code the repository into the dependency information, then we loose relocatability.